# Is assignment from control flow (ifs, switches) good style?

Tags: coding-style, variable-assignment, indentation

I've seen a lot of code written like this;

```
conditional_value = if thing_is_true
                      true_value
                    else
                      other_value
                    end
```

I feel conflicted about this. On one hand it's nice to use the return value of the conditional (or any other syntactic chunk like switches, begin/ends, loops, or even function definitions) to reduce redundancy and make it clear what the code is doing. On the other hand, the indentation is often jarring and confusing.

As a second possibility, if one decides to have all lines indented to the level of the beginning of the first line, that destroys the visual cue of the whole structure.

```
conditional_value = if thing_is_true
  true_value
else
  other_value
end
```

Here's a third alternative (at least in Ruby) relying on line breaks;

```
conditional_value =
  if thing_is_true
    true_value
  else
    other_value
  end
```

A fourth alternative is to bite the bullet and put the assignment statement in every branch.

```
if thing_is_true
  conditional_value = true_value
else
  conditional_value = other_value
end
```

I'm wary of this becoming an 'opinions' question, but I think there are *facts* I don't know;

- How often are these styles seen in professional code?
- How easy is it for people to read?
- Do any of these styles commonly cause bugs?
- In what ways do these styles maintain or break the integrity of the visual presentation of the code?

Answer (score 3):

I would only assign the result of a ternary operator `val = condition ? true_value: false_value`, not the value of an `if` expression. This may just be a habit from Java/C/C++, but using `if` this way does seem to potentially confuse flow control with expression value. Your fourth alternative above would be OK in this style.

But if you have a consistent style that includes using the value of `if`, it's fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it definitely makes it clearer to the reader what the intention of the code is when it starts with the assignment. That is, if I'm debugging that code and I already know that the variable assigned from the conditional is behaving itself (ie: not the source of the bug), then I can completely skip over that entire block, without spending brain cycles figuring out if there's side effects inside there.

In languages without a terse `if else` format, it can definitely become cumbersome, however in languages which have the ternary operator (`? :`) and a sensible order of operations (read: not PHP), I quite like this style also for arbitrarily nested conditionals:

```
var x = someCondition ? a
      : somethingElse ? b
      : anotherThing  ? c
                      : d;
```